# ASM Tree API: Using LDC to load a Class<?> constant

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm writing a program in ASM that uses the Tree API to add bytecode to some methods. I've used ASMifier to generate the code required to create a specific method, but I'm having some trouble with the following line:

```
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getType('L' + targetClassName + ';'));
```

I've simply initialized mv to a `new MethodNode`, but instead of loading the `Class`, the above line appears in bytecode as:

```
ldc Lsome/test/TestClass; (org.objectweb.asm.Type)
```

How can I make ASM load the `java/lang/Class` constant instead of an `org.objectweb.asm.Type` constant?

If it's related, the next line of bytecode would be `invokevirtual java/lang/Class getClassLoader(()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;);`

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you use the Tree API *and* `visitLdcInsn`. With `MethodNode` I would expect that new instructions are inserted into [`InsnList`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/InsnList.html).

Comment: I'm using ASMifier, and then simply replacing the ```MethodVisitor``` with a ```MethodNode```, because that seems to be the simplest way of converting a generated method into something that can be used in the Tree API. As far as I can tell, the ```LdcInsnNode``` is simply added to the ```InsnList``` in the implementation of visitLdcInsn anyway.

Comment: You are having a mistake in the conversion process. Otherwise, this seems correct.

Comment: Conversion process? I just get the bytes from a ```ClassWriter``` after ```ClassNode#accept(ClassWriter)```

Comment: There are no constants of type `org.objectweb.asm.Type` in Java byte code. You are just misinterpreting your own output.

Comment: That's what confused me even more. This is the output of a disassembler, not anything I've created.

Comment: Which disassembler did you use? Anything that is based on ASM and therefore could show ASM artifacts when printing the result?

Comment: The disassembler tool on https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, though not the canonical solution. You can simplify it as

```
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getObjectType(targetClassName));
```

(In ASM, “Object Type” means a reference type, see also [`Type.getObjectType(…)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getObjectType(java.lang.String)) and [the `Type.OBJECT` sort](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#OBJECT)). However, the result is the same. The reason, why the disassembly output looks like

```
ldc Lsome/test/TestClass; (org.objectweb.asm.Type)
```

lies in the disassembler. If you look at [it’s code for converting an LDC instruction to a `String`](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer/blob/master/src/main/java/the/bytecode/club/bytecodeviewer/decompilers/bytecode/InstructionPrinter.java#L188):

> ```
> protected String printLdcInsnNode(LdcInsnNode ldc, ListIterator<?> it) {
>     if (ldc.cst instanceof String)
>         return nameOpcode(ldc.opcode()) + " \"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(ldc.cst.toString()) + "\" (" + ldc.cst.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ")";
>
>    return nameOpcode(ldc.opcode()) + " " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(ldc.cst.toString()) + " (" + ldc.cst.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ")";
> }
> ```

you will see that it will print the type of the object instance stored in the `LdcInsnNode` rather than what the code will eventually produce at runtime. For a `String`, this is sufficient as its the same type, and for primitives it will print the corresponding wrapper type, but for `Type` or `Handle` objects, this disassembler will show you these ASM specific classes instead of the corresponding runtime classes `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.invoke.MethodType` or `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`, which the `ldc` instruction will actually push to the operand stack.

Comment: Right, thanks. I checked with another disassembler, and I get the correct java/lang/Class constant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a temporary workaround for now.

```
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles", "lookup", "()Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;", false);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup", "lookupClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;", false);
```

Comment: There seems to be no relation to the problem above. It seems that the text above was not your real problem ...

Comment: The objective was to load a Class<?> constant onto the stack. I originally tried to use LDC, this is another method of doing the same thing.